# Output an array with multiple cards in each row in Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

I receive a JSON from a get request which I pass to an array

```js
stnArray: [{ Station: string; StnRef: string; }] =[{Station:"Station", StnRef:"Station Reference"}]
```

I wish to output 2 or 3 cards per row in the DOM however I'm only getting one per row using the code below in my HTML.

```html
<div class='row wow fadeInUp' *ngFor='let index of stnArray;; let i = index; let even = even'>
  <span *ngIf="even">
     <div class='col-md-3 pull-left'  *ngIf="stnArray[i+1]">
      <div class="card-deck" 
      style="cursor: pointer"           
      (click)="updateStationRef(i)">
           <div class="card-block">
                  <h4 class="card-title">
                    {{stnArray[i].Station}}</h4>
                    
                    <p class="card-text"> ({{stnArray[i].StnRef }}) </p>
                </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class='col-md-3 pull-right'  *ngIf="stnArray[i+1]">
      <div class="card-deck"
      style="cursor: pointer"           
      (click)="updateStationRef(i+1)">
           <div class="card-block">
                  <h4 class="card-title">
                    {{stnArray[i+1].Station}}</h4>
                    
            <p class="card-text"> ({{stnArray[i+1].StnRef }}) </p>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing `i+1` ? share code where you initialized `i`

Comment: its not angular thing, you need to do it using html or css, ngFor only iterates over the div, not to do anything with design or templates

Answer (score -1):

You can use *ngFor directive of angular. It will iterate over the array automatically and will be useful in this kinda of scenario.

Basic example would be like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}}</div>
```

In this case, items is an array of object. ie [{name: 'Michael'}, {name: 'Bharat'}]

Please refer the below given link :

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/
https://mdbootstrap.com/support/angular/multiple-cards-using-ngfor/

I hope, it answers your question :)

Comment: Hi Bharat, thanks for the answer, though I'm already using *ngFor and the issue is that it each item it outputs takes up an entire row rather than stacking up with 2 items per row.